# How to I convert ADO.NET file or the whole data model designed in ADO.NET to entity frameowrk as the other projects are in EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net

In MVC 5 ,In my project I have a fileuploading class file with ado.net connection strings and I have other files and data designed in EF. how do I change the code in order to switch from ado.net to EF?

Answer (score 0):

this is a so generally question, but, you need to remove the ado objects, and implement this functionality in EF, using the EF Context, ensure that the dbcontext has the dbset that you need, etc...

Also, if you have more specific questions is better!